# header file error in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

I am newbie in visual c++.i have created a small program,but its showing error C1083.

My program is like this:

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
cout <<"Welcome to cpp program";
}
```

the error report is :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: payroll, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  first_page.cpp
1>c:\users\naga\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\payroll\payroll\first_page.cpp(1): 
fatal error C1083:
 Cannot open include file: 'iostream.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

i have seen that i should do something with the properties.But i didnt understand that stuff.Also When i click the toolbar and property window,no item appears inside them.I doubt this comes coz i have selected win 32 console application???

Comment: Try `#include <iostream>` instead. And make sure you declare your `main` properly...

Comment: You'll need to find a more up to date book.  iostream.h has been outdated for 15 years already.  You'll need to use `<iostream>` and use the std namespace.  Burn the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std include headers do not need the .h

```
#include <iostream>
```

should work.

Comment: i dont understand why items of toolbar and property tool doesnt appear??